# how to edit keyboards of telegram bot?

Tags: php, bots, telegram

How can I edit the keyboards of the telegram bot?

For inline_keyboards I used editMessageText as:

```html
$url2 = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$token."/editMessageText?parse_mode=HTML&chat_id=".$chat_id."&text=".urlencode($text)."&message_id=".$message_id."&reply_markup=".$reply;
```

I don't know how to use this for simple keyboards.

Comment: You need to send new message.

Comment: why i send again??